# Nest.js - Create index in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

How do I create an index of property in mongoose schema using Nest.js?

I tried to add index as a property option, But the index hasn't been created:

```
@Schema()
export class Schema extends Document {

  @Prop()
  _id: string;

  @Prop({required: true, index: true})
  type: string;

  @Prop()
  creationDate: string;

  @Prop()
  name: string;
}

export const MySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Schema);
```

I tried this way too:

```
export const MySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Schema).index({ type: 1 });
```

Both doesn't work as expected.

What is the way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: both solutions should work, is `Document` imported from mongoose?

Comment: Yes, Document is imported from 'mongoose'. when running the service i get this warning:  DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead, so I guess, something happened with my index, but the only index in this collection is "_id"

Comment: do you need to tell to the schema that a field is an index if that already is set in the mongodb?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use following option to create index

```
    @Schema({useCreateIndex: true})
    export class Schema extends Document {
    
      @Prop()
      _id: string;
    
      @Prop({required: true, index: true})
      type: string;
    
      @Prop()
      creationDate: string;
    
      @Prop()
      name: string;
    }

export const MySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Schema);
```

use `useCreateIndex` flag either when defining the schema

or globally set the same flag when creating the connection object

```
 {
  uri: `....`,
  user: ,
  pass: ,
  //useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  //useUnifiedTopology: true,
  //useFindAndModify: false,
  retryAttempts: 3
}
```

Added other commented flags as well which could be required.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me

```js
export const MySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Schema);
MySchema.index({ type: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Same can be extended for compound index as well - ex:

```js
MySchema.index({ type: 1, name: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Answer (score 6):

If someone came here looking for how to add index for a geo location/2dsphere, just like me, You can use the following in NestJs.

```
@Prop({ index: "2dsphere" })
```

Also when you are setting up the mongoose module, add `useCreateIndex: true`.

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
 useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
   uri: config.get('mongo_url'),
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useCreateIndex: true,
 }),
 inject: [ConfigService],
})
```