# How to create TTL based schema in NestJs using mangoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to create self destructive schema in **NestJs(typeScript)** project using `mangoose` and `@nestjs/mongoose` library, but couldn't able to rectify a way to implement it . I know how to do it in express framework using js but didn't found any documentation for TS with NestJs

Also updated my code like below ,but still isn't working

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory, SchemaOptions } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mangoose from 'mongoose';

export type OtpDocument = Otp & mangoose.Document;

// @Schema({ timestamps: { createdAt: { type: Date, expires: 20 } } })
@Schema()
export class Otp {
  @Prop({ type: mangoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  user: any;

  @Prop({ expires: 3600 })
  OTP: number;

  @Prop()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Prop({ default: Date.now() + 20000 })
  expireAt: Date;
}

export const OtpSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Otp);
OtpSchema.index({ expiresAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });
```

Comment: Are you talking about `expires` mongoose? Maybe you can share how you would do it in “express”.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose

Comment: So referring to that question. What have you tried specifically? Have you tried adding `expires` to `createdAt` property? Have you tried creating an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421526/nest-js-create-index-in-mongoose-schema)? What issues did you encounter when adding those pieces?

Comment: yes tried that as well ,still isn't working ,wait i will update the question

Comment: TTL only works with Date types. You are trying to apply to a Number which will not work.

Comment: can u elaborate more using code ?

Comment: It seems like you already did it in your answer

Comment: yeah,figured it out ,was a silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

It works on Date type ,and can be achieved by adding expires property in `@Props` decorater ,like

```
 @Prop({ type: Date, expires: '2m', default: Date.now })
  createdAt: Date;
```

for more reference here's the full code

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mangoose from 'mongoose';
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

export type OtpDocument = Otp & mangoose.Document;

    @Schema()
    export class Otp {
      @Prop({ type: Date, expires: '2m', default: Date.now })
      createdAt: Date;
    
      @Prop()
      otp: number;
    }
    
    export const OtpSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Otp);
```